# how to show div content dynamically based on what javascript returns in success function?

Tags: ajax, jquery, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

```
$.ajax({
        url :addToDo,            
          data: {"rest_name":camp_ID,
              "f_start_date":f_start_date,
              "f_end_date":f_end_date,
              "CMD":camp_ID},
          type: "GET",
          timeout: 20000,
          dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {  
            $("#mydiv").load("<%=reportURL.toString()%>");
        }
    });
}
```

Following is my portlet render tag:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="reportURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/htmlreport/report.html" />
</portlet:renderURL>
```

I have this above ajax function and on success of that function I want to fill one div dynamically with html page's content. Its working for one static page right now.

so can anyone guide me how I can make fill the div with success function. My problem is that how can I fill div with one html page in success.. as which html page is only defined after ajax executes successfully every time function will generate different html file.

Comment: I suppose you should return the url in the data you receive from the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
success: function(data) {  
    $("#mydiv").load(data);
}
```

Here `data` is what you written back from the server. It can be a URL as suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775924/how-to-show-div-dynamicaly-based-on-what-java-script-reurn-in-success#comment18947231_13775924). So this becomes dynamic based on what your return from the server method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what i know is we cant give direct url to load the page..we need to pass in renderurl first

Comment: So you are saying you can't create a render-url in the server method?